# How to apply udf on a dataframe and on a column in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am beginner to scala. I tried `scala REPL` window in `intellij`.
I have a sample df and trying to test `udf function` not `builtin` for understanding.

*df*:

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
 val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.appName("elephant").config("spark.master", "local[*]").getOrCreate()
 val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(("A",1),("B",2),("C",3))).toDF("Letter", "Number")
 df.show()
```

*output*:

```
|Letter|Number|
+------+------+
|     A|     1|
|     B|     2|
|     C|     3|
+------+------+
```

*udf for dataframe filter:*

```
scala> def kill_4(n: String) : Boolean = {
     | if (n =="A"){ true} else {false}} // please validate if its correct ???
```

*I tried*

```
df.withColumn("new_col", kill_4(col("Letter"))).show() // please tell correct way???
```

**error**
`error: type mismatch`

Second:
I tried direct filter:

```
df.filter(kill_4(col("Letter"))).show()
```

**output desired**

```
+------+------+
|Letter|Number|
+------+------+
|     B|     2| 
|     C|     3| 
+------+------+-
```

Comment: The function `kill_4` is a Scala function which can't be used with a DataFrame as a UDF. I would suggest going through the Spark documentation to understand how UDFs are written and how are they executed over the DataFrame

Comment: you could say < keep trying> its same thing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register udf and use it in code as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

def kill_4(n: String) : Boolean = {
     if (n =="A"){ true } else {false}
}
 
val kill_udf = udf((x: String) => kill_4(x))

df.select(col("Letter"),col("Number")
    kill_udf(col("Letter")).as("Kill_4") ).show(false)
```

Comment: Can you please apply same function on list?

Comment: You can use the function directly using Scala List's map method: 

lst.map(x => kill_4(x.toString()))
Output: List[Boolean] = List(true, false, false)

Comment: df.select(col("Letter"),col("Number"),
    kill_udf(col("Letter")).as("Kill_4") ).show(false) //comma was missing there

Answer (score 2):

Please look at the databricks documentation on scala user defined funcitons.

https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-scala.html

[image]

You do not need the spark session to create a dataframe.  I removed that code.

[image]

Your function had a couple bugs.  Since it is very small, I created a inline one.  The udf() call allows the function to be used with dataframes.  The call to register allows it to be used with Spark SQL.

A quick SQL statement shows the function works.

[image]

Last but not least, we need the udf() and col() functions for the last statement to work.

In short, these three snippets solve your problem.

Comment: can you please apply fun on the list?